# Will Changing the Max Memory Setting Invalidate Query Plans?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory, configuration, plan-cache

I recently lowered the max memory from the default (unlimited) down to 20 GB. Does this erase the oldest queries in the plan cache?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql) changing the max server memory will clear the plan cache, as will changing:

- access check cache bucket count
- access check cache quota
- clr enabled
- cost threshold for parallelism
- cross db ownership chaining
- index create memory
- max degree of parallelism
- max server memory
- max text repl size
- max worker threads
- min memory per query
- min server memory
- query governor cost limit
- query wait
- remote query timeout
- user options